# Determine binding object that triggers context menu in WPF container?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

(this entire inquiry is predicated on the assumption that I can create a context menu in a separate file and attach it to different containers in different controls - that assumption should be verified)

How do I determine the binding object in a container item that triggers a context menu action?

I can see how to do it by looking at the SelectedItem of the ListView but I prefer not to have to know about the particular ListView instance, e.g. so the same context menu can be attached to different lists.

Is there a general-purpose solution to determining the binding object, even in different types of containers (e.g. not necessarily a ListView)?

```
<UserControl ...>

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="Caption" Click="MenuItem_Click"></MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <ListView x:Name="ListView">
        <ListView.ContextMenu>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="ContextMenu" />
        </ListView.ContextMenu>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

</UserControl>
```

Given the above control, how to get to the binding object for item that was clicked?
I am drowning in property soup in RoutedEventArgs.

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var obj = ??? as MyObjType;
  var name = obj.Name;
}
```

This seems to work as expected, but is hard-coded to the container instance:

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var obj = (MyObjType)NodesList.SelectedItem;
    MessageBox.Show(obj.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go with a generalized apporach you can try simply getting the control by mouse coordinates. You'll need to get them when menu opens:

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenu" Opened="ContextMenu_Opened">
   <MenuItem Header="Caption" Click="MenuItem_Click" />
</ContextMenu>
```

Then use when item is finally clicked

```
private void ContextMenu_Opened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var p = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
   var element = this.InputHitTest(p) as FrameworkElement;

   if (element != null)
   {
      //your data object
      ((ContextMenu)sender).DataContext = element.DataContext;
   }
}

private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var boundObject = ((MenuItem)sender).DataContext;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you apply the `ContextMenu` to an individual item instead of applying it to the `ItemsControl` itself...:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="Caption" Click="MenuItem_Click"></MenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ListView x:Name="ListView">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ContextMenu}" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

...you could get a reference to the data item through the `PlacementTarget` of the `ContextMenu`. You can then cast it to a `FrameworkElement` to be able to access its `DataContext`:

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MenuItem mi = (MenuItem)sender;
    ContextMenu cm = mi.Parent as ContextMenu;
    if (cm != null)
    {
        FrameworkElement fe = cm.PlacementTarget as FrameworkElement;
        if (fe != null)
        {
            object dataItem = fe.DataContext;
            //...
        }
    }
}
```